# How GNU Make makes a decision which intermediate files to remove and which to keep

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I've read the [official documentation about chains of implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html#Chained-Rules) and I believe that this is the reason why I observe this behavior, although I can't quite comprehend why.

Let's say we have the following `Makefile`:

```
.DELETE_ON_ERROR:
.PHONY: all

SOURCES := $(wildcard *.source)
RESULTS := $(SOURCES:.source=/done)

%/a %/b %/c : %.source
    mkdir $* && cd $* && touch a && touch b && touch c

%/d : %/a
    cd $* && touch d

%/done : %/d %/b %/c
    touch $@

all : $(RESULTS)
    echo "Handled: $^"
```

If i go to some local directory and do the following steps:

```
$ touch 123.source
$ make
mkdir 123 && cd 123 && touch a && touch b && touch c
cd 123 && touch d
touch 123/done
echo "Handled: 123/done"
Handled: 123/done
rm 123/d 123/a
```

The thing that looks confusing to me is that `make` only removes `d` and `a`, but not the rest of the intermediate files, why so? The same happens when `make` fails. If I insert an `exit 1` step inside a rule for `%/done`, then `make` will remove `a` and `d` upon failure and will keep the rest of the files.

So my questions would be:

1. Why `make` decides to remove `a` and `d` in case of success while keeping the rest of the files? I don't see a reason why these are removed. In case `a` and `d` are parts of implicit chain of rules, then the same must be applied to `b` and `c`, because they also don't exist when `make` starts.
2. Why in case of failure, `make` removes only `a` and `d`, but not `b` and `c`? I would expect `.DELETE_ON_ERROR` to remove them as well and I can't explain this behavior. It behaves as if `b` and `c` were defined as `.PRECIOUS`.

Comment: Seems like a bug to me.  Rather than what you suggest, I believe it more likely that the handling of grouped targets is not interacting with intermediate files properly.  You might consider filing a bug about it.

Comment: I agree with @MadScientist. If you run `make -p` you can notice that only `123/a` and `123/d` are marked as intermediate (`#  File is an intermediate prerequisite.`) hence only those two are removed.